# how to display element firstname and lastname ... from strore redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, use-state

find here my code whene I try to get firstName I get the issue “Cannot read properties of undefined” could some one give a solution or expalain what's the issue whith my code

```
let state = useSelector(state => {
      // console.log('State: ', state.profile);
       return state.profile;
     });


   const [profile, setProfile] = useState();
   const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
       isValid: false,
       values: {},
       touched: {},
       errors: {}
   });

   useEffect(()=>{
       console.log({accesstoken: token});
   if(token)
       dispatch(profileActions.getInfos({accesstoken: token}));
   },[])


   useEffect(()=>{
       if (state)
       setProfile(state)
       console.log(profile.profile);
   },[state, profile])
```

```
/// here the peace of code to display the profile.data.firstname
ListItemText primary="Date de creation" secondary{JSON.stringify(profile.data.firstName)} />
```

[image: in a debug i could get state with selector in usestate]

Answer (score 0):

Did you console the variable state just before your useEffect.
I guess no need to use (useState & useEffect) you can directly use yout variable state.
try to add a console.log(state) before or after the useEffect and share it with as.

Comment: find bello my response

Comment: what's do you think about this error

Comment: are you did  .json() to your api response in redux action ?

Comment: I think is a problem with the default state because always the first init dont work